# CA2000 When returning the disposable object (using a try/finally block)

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, ca2000, microsoft-code-analysis

In C#, we are trying to properly handle the disposition of an object in a method that returns it (or rather, it sets it as another object's property and returns the other object). Following what the docs state, the error CA2000 still jumps.

We tried using the try/finally statement as it is displayed in the C# documentation: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000.md
Example:

```
public static ApiRequestData Method(ApiRequestData request, byte[] contents)
{
    var content = (HttpContent)request.Content;

    ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = null;
    try 
    { 
        byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(contents);
    
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain; charset=iso-8859-5");
        content.Add(byteArrayContent, "fieldName", "fileName");
        byteArrayContent = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        byteArrayContent?.Dispose();
    }

    return request;
}
```

We also tried returning inside the try block, but unless we remove the `byteArrayContent = null;`, CA2000 jumps.
Another thing we tried is removing the `byteArrayContent = null;` block and changing the finally clause to a catch clause, but CA2000 still jumps.

Is it a false positive, are we doing something wrong? What should we be doing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `request`? You're returning that rather than `content`, but you're not disposing of `content`. It doesn't help that your method declaration is invalid to start with. Please provide a [mcve] rather than pseudocode.

Comment: Please provide actual code that reproduces the issue. Your method signature is incorrect (no return type) and you `return request;` but `request` is not declared anywhere in the code shown.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a `using` block or statement?

Comment: As is, `byteArrayContent.Dispose();` _will_ throw a NRE. Either because it is not yet something else than null or because it _is_ null _again_. And if you set it null _before_ you dispose it ... you're not going to be able to anymore.

Comment: Can you just post the [mcve] instead of fixing what we throw in on-the-fly?

Comment: Probably went to far with code redaction. Now it should be more correct

Comment: So, now `Dispose()` will still never be called... now you are hiding the issue instead of fixing it.

Comment: See this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tOtOYZ

Comment: That is the intended behaviour, (dispose is only called in case of exception) the only thing I don't understand is why the error keeps jumping

Comment: Ahaa ... in _that_ case, I think bullet point 2 in this list : https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000.md#when-to-suppress-warnings applies to your code? And maybe also point 3. Which means in short: I think it's ok to just mute the warning.

Comment: And the reason you are getting it (the warning) is because the code _looks like_ you are creating an object of a type that implements `IDisposable`, but you don't dispose it. I guess the static analysis is not smart enough to see that the responsibility to dispose is transferred to the `HttpContent`.